# SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier import React from 'react'

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

When I run tests using Jest I get the error `SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier` and it points to the line `import React from 'react'`

I have a pretty basic project setup: I am not using create-react-app or a bundler like Webpack or Rollup.

My npm scripts and dependencies are:

````
    "react": "^16.12.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.12.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build": "babel --watch src --out-dir ./dist --presets react-app/prod",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.7.7",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.7.7",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.7.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.4.0",
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-jest": "^24.9.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.6",
    "babel-preset-react-app": "^3.1.2",
    "jest": "^24.9.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "^16.12.0"
  }```

I also have a `.babelrc`: ```{
    "presets": [
        "@babel/preset-react"
    ]
}```

Link to repo: https://github.com/o-t-w/test-lib
````

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: This error occurs when I am running a test using the command line.